# Is the path of `Context.getFilesDir` stable over the lifecycle of an application?

Tags: android, file

I pass a reference to the files directory of my app `Context.getFilesDir()` to an asynchronous function in order to save a downloaded file.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()) states:

> The returned path may change over time if the calling app is moved to an adopted storage device, so only relative paths should be persisted.

Should I worry that the storage path might switch up under me while the app is used, or will the application be torn down and recreated when the files directory changes?

Equivalently, is it okay to call `Context.getFilesDir()` once on startup, and keep a reference to this value, or should I call `Context.getFilesDir()` again every chance I get?

Comment: Persisting only relative paths implies using always Context.getFilesDir().

Comment: That is: persisting across app sessions. That makes sense, but my question is within one session of an app.